# Using sticky figures above bars in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this [chart](https://jsfiddle.net/1ez0Lo8a/8/) setup in which I have the values on the bars using the animation `onComplete`

```
animation: {
      onComplete: function () {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
            ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.data[index];
            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);

          });
        });
      }
```

This works, as you can see, the figures sit atop the bars - however when you hover over the bar it kind of flashes due to the animation effect.

I prefer it not be in this animation effect so it does not flash like this - is there an alternative way to produce what I've done here, without the flash/animation when you hover ?

Comment: Should the number appear all the time ? when do u want to show them ?

Comment: They should appear all the time above the bar - hence "sticky" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, instead of "onComplete" u should use "onProgress" . Try this code :

```
animation: {
      onProgress: function () {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
            ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.data[index];
            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);

          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: thank you! at least someone understood me :)